# Setting permissions to write and read from /var/www

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I need that directory, as I want to put my sites there, so that apache can run them.

It is my virtual directory path. I am new to linux. I just want to read and write from that directory.

**What command do I give to enable creating/saving/reading files/folders in that directory?**

I tried a few, but I think I need to be a super user to make the folder writtable readable.

Note that I dont care about security.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ su
<enter the root password here, as asked>
# mkdir -fp /var/www
# chmod -R 777 /var/www
# exit
```

If you tell us what OS you're on, how you set up Apache, what you want it to do and post (an abridget version of) `ls -lR /var/www`, you might get an answer which is less dangerous and more useful.

Comment: Hint: If you're using `chmod 777` you're most likely doing something wrong. Making something world-writable (especially on a server) can yield interesting results. And by interesting, I mean that you'll most likely run into trouble.